# Superfish Full Width Mega Menu

Tags: css, positioning, superfish, megamenu

I am Working on [Superfish](http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/#sample1) Menu to a FullWidth Mega menu. But I failed to get the position of dropdown as fullwidth; i.e streched along the entire length of menu rather than the absolute positioning I'm getting, Any suggetion with CSS will be helpful.